# inserting data in one-to-one relationship belongsTo Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have two schema

- address
- employee

Each employee will have one address so, mine schema is as below

*employee.js*

```
const address = conn.define('address', {
    street: Sequelize.TEXT,
    city: Sequelize.STRING,
    postalCode: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const employee = conn.define('employee', {
    empId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    joinDateTime: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
});

address.belongsTo(employee);

employee.sync();
address.sync();
module.exports = employee;
```

Below is the Insertation Logic, It doesn't work, how can i perform association insertion

Item is an object from the array, where i have performed the forEach

```
const obj = {
    empId: item.empId,
    name: item.name,
    joinDateTime: item.joinDateTime,
};
const address = {
    street: item.street,
    city: item.city,
    postalCode: item.postalCode,
};
Employee.build(obj).save().then((resp) => {
    /* here how can i perform the insertion in associated address schema
obj.address(address) won't work */
    obj.address(address).then(() => console.log('created')).catch(err => 
    console.log(err));
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add two pieces of code.

In your first snippet, add

```
employee.hasOne(address);
```

In your second one, change

```
Employee.build(obj).save().then((resp) => {
    /* here how can i perform the insertion in associated address schema
obj.address(address) won't work */
    obj.address(address).then(() => console.log('created')).catch(err => 
    console.log(err));
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

to

```
Employee.build(obj).save().then((employee) => {
    employee.setAddress(address).then(() => console.log('created')).catch(err => 
    console.log(err));
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Note: obj.address(address) becomes obj.setAddress(address).

Please let us know if this works!

Comment: it throws an error `TypeError:obj.setAddress(address) `, as obj is just primitive type not an instance?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. In `obj` is now the newly created `employee` which is passed to the then-function of the save method.